# Estructura sobre Threads en Java Swing

Tags: java, java-swing, hilos, java-8, combobox

Pongo a disposición mi primera consulta y de antemano agradezco las futuras respuestas.

Para empezar tengo un formulario que contiene 2 `jcombobox`:

`jcbSerie` y `jcbPartido`.

El formulario integra

```
Runnable()
```

En las variables del formulario tengo un `Thread` y un `int`:

```
Thread Serie = new Thread();
int opt = 1;
```

Al inicializar el formulario se ejecuta:

```
Serie.start();
```

lo inicializo con `start()` porque me informe de que la diferencia con `run()` es que éste se ejecuta asíncronamente.
En el fragmento `run()` *<= metodo de ejecucion*, se encuentra el código a ejecutar el cual tiene el siguiente formato:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    switch (opt) {
        case 1:
               MetodoEjecutado1();
            break;
        case 2:
               MetodoEjecutado2();
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
    }
}
```

Entonces, como es de esperarse, se ejecuta el condicional 1 al ejecutarse el formulario. Pero mi consulta es la siguiente: Como o cual es la forma en que deberia ejecutar el condicional 2 del `run()` desde `jcbPartido`. Para ser mas preciso :

> Ejecutar el MetodoEjecutado1() solo una vez y que el thread ya no este disponible o destruirlo (soy nuevo estoy dispuesto a leer las respuestas);
>
> En el evento de cambio de item de jcbSerie si selecciona un valor diferente a la opcion "Seleccionar opcion" desbloquea el jcombobox jcbPartido.
>
> Al cambiar de item en jcbPartido la variable `opt` que vale 1 cambia a `opt = 2`, entonces como puedo ejecutar el metodo *run()* que solo ejecute una sola vez MetodoEjecutado2() asíncronamente, e igual que la primera parte, que muera o pare al acabar.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo!.

Comment: Podrias solo como referencia mirar el [tour] y [ask]. Tu pregunta esta muy bien redactada, es solo para que sepas como funcionamos ;)

Comment: @gbianchi lo tendre en cuenta, como especifico es mi primera pregunta asi que trate de hacerla lo mejor estructurada :(

Comment: Lo mio fue un halago, es mas los 4 votos positivos que tenes me avalan ;).

Comment: @PabloLozano jcbPartido se carga asíncronamente al iniciar formulario pero el _Thread_ no puedo detenerlo, mi codigo ejecuta el hilo en bucle

Comment: Supongo que esto es un ejercicio para practicar: ¿tienes restricciones en cuanto a qué usar? Lo digo porque lo que me parece más útil en este caso es usar un SwingWorker para lanzar threads y esperar a que terminen sin bloquear la UI

Comment: @PabloLozano gracias por el dato, es exactamente lo que tu estas diciendo, buscar documentación sobre lo que me mencionas, Gracias!

Comment: te sugiero leer este articulo : sindominio.net/ayuda/preguntas-inteligentes.html de como hacer buenas preguntas , porque te lo aseguro esta pregunta no tiene nada que ver con stackoverflow, te sugiero buscar en google :) y si no sabes como se crean las buenas preguntas aqui, te recomiendo leer el tour : es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

Veo 2 soluciones a tu problema.
Una sencilla pero poco elegante:

```
@Override
public void run() {
  try {
    while(true){
      switch (opt) {
          case 1:
              MetodoEjecutado1();
              opt = 3;
              break;
          case 2:
              MetodoEjecutado2();
              opt = 3;
              break;
          case 3:
              //Espera indefinidamente a una modificación externa de opt.
              sleep(100);
              break;
      }
    }
  }catch(InterruptedException e){
    //exception necesaria del sleep.
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

De esta forma, solo has de crear una instancia de la clase Serie y iniciar el Thread.
Si es necesario parar el thread, lo puedes hacer en qualquier momento con Serie.interrupt();

Y una segunda solución que obliga al programador a crear nuevas instancias del Thread cada vez que se quiere ejecutar este pero es mas limpia.

El código de **run()** solo se puede iniciar una sola vez por instancia. 
Una vez terminadas las instrucciones dentro de **run()**, el Thread se interrumpe automáticamente.

De esta forma, podrías instanciar Serie, decidir que opción quieres ejecutar, y llamar el método Serie.start();

Si estas trabajando con Threads i Swing te recomiendo investigar [este post](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-use-threads-in-java-swing/) y este [articulo de oracle.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Recientemente he experimentado con encolamientos de solicitudes y procesos asíncronos que van limpiando la cola de solicitudes. Te comparto la lógica que uso:

En primer lugar, voy llenando una lista de tareas a ejecutar, digamos `List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();` donde el entero será el tipo de tarea a ejecutar.

Las acciones de los comboboxes irán llenando la lista, agregando elementos al final de la misma, mientras que la lectura de estos elementos irá quitando items del inicio de la lista.

#### Clase que controla las acciones de los comboboxes

```
class ProcesarCombos {
    ...
    // Acción del combobox:
    lista.add(valorCombobox);
    ...
}
```

#### Clase Runnable()

```
@Override
public void run() {
    for(;;){ // Ciclo infinito
        if(lista.size > 0){ // Validar que la lista tiene valores
            int opt = lista.remove(0); // Obtener y eliminar el primer elemento de la lista
            switch(opt){
                case 1:
                    MetodoEjecutado1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    MetodoEjecutado2();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

De esta forma, la función `run()` contendrá un hilo constantemente esperando a que la lista de acciones contenga valores, y una vez que encuentre uno, llamará el método correspondiente. Una vez finalizado, volverá a validar en la lista si hay nuevos valores, y así hasta que termine por vaciar la lista.

Haciendo la lista una variable estática o pasada por parámetro al constructor de la clase `Runnable()`, podremos usar la misma lista en ambos procesos, de manera que, de forma asíncrona, podamos ir llenando e iterando la lista al mismo tiempo.

Espero que mi ejemplo te sea de utilidad.